# Linear sieving algorithm

Tags: sieve, pari

Is there a simple pari/gp program which can sieve numbers of the form k*n+c (where n and c fixed) up to a certain prime p and k is restricted within a certain range (a.k.a. for(k=1,10000,)?

Pseudocode:

```
n = (some number);
c = (some number);
T=[all k values];
forprime(p=2,100000000, for(i=1,#List if((T[i]*n+c)%p==0, (remove the number T[i] from the list)
```

In other words, start with a list of integers T
Test the first prime in the prime range p, and remove integers k from the list T such that k*n+c is divisible by p. Then test the next prime and so on. Do this until you reached the limit of the sieve
return, or print the list of candidates.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudo code you provide seems to be reasonable. Rather than removing from the list it is probably easier and as efficient to just copy it. Use the function `select` to keep those elements that should be retained rather than removed.

Some actual code:

```
sieve(n,c,plimit,L)={forprime(p=2, plimit, L=select(t->(t*n+c)%p, L); if(!#L, break)); L}
sieve(8, 3, 70000, [1..10000])
```

I have also added a check in the loop to exit the loop if the list becomes empty. In the cases I have tried, this seems to happen.

Comment: If n and c are small then a much more efficient method would be to just factor each of the k*n+c for k in 1..10000. However, for sufficiently large n factoring becomes prohibitively slow.

Comment: For large n/c might there be a more efficient method/algorithm? That is really a mathematical question rather than a PARI coding question.